# How can I add a class with table theme function to a table header row?

Tags: theming

How can I apply a class to the `<tr>` of some table headers using the table theme function?

So, I get this: `<tr class='my-class'><th>foo</th><th>bar</th></tr>`

...rather than: `<tr><th class='my-class'>foo</th><th class='my-class'>bar</th></tr>`

...which is all I've managed with this:

```
$section = array(
  '#theme' => 'table',
  '#header' => array(
    array('data' => 'foo', 'class' => 'my-class',),
    array('data' => 'bar', 'class' => 'my-class',),
  ),
  '#rows' => $rows,
),
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Drupal 6 or 7?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using below code

```
 $section = array(
      //It contains the rows
      array( 
        //'data' contains cell data as numerical arrays:
        'data' => array(
          //Cell 1: array if need to add classes in cells too
          array('data' => 'Cell 1', 'class' => 'cell-class1'),
          //Cell 2:
          array('data' => 'Cell 2', 'class' => 'cell-class2'),

        ),
        //Row attributes, e.g. 'class', 'rel','data'
        'class' => array('row-class1'),
      ),
      //Contains the rows, is a numerical array (as default): 0, 1, 2 ... :
      array( 

        'data' => array(
                array('data' => 'Cell#1', 'class' => 'cell-class1'),
                array('data' => 'Cell#2', 'class' => 'cell-class1'),
        ),
        'class' => array('row-class2'),
      ),
    );
```

Hope it will help!

Comment: Note this example no longer works for Drupal 8 due to #attributes and #wrapper_attributes.  It is fairly confusing, so here is a working example:  http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/228993/3167

Answer (score 1):

If your current example works I'm assuming you are on drupal 6.

You can add attributes to the header array like this:

```
$section = array(
  '#theme' => 'table',
  '#header' => array(
    array('data' => 'foo', 'class' => 'cell-class'),
    array('data' => 'bar', 'class' => 'cell-class'),
    'class' => 'row-class',
  ),
  '#rows' => $rows,
),
```