# Add a class to a Drupal table cell containing ['data']

Tags: theming, 8

In Drupal 8,  rendering Tables is still a lot like Drupal 7.  You build out  multi-dimensional arrays of rows and columns in PHP that Drupal transforms into a `<tr>` and `<td>`s respectively.  There is still this confusing Drupalism known as `'data'` that lets you add render array elements as cell data (not to be confused with data attributes).

I've been given a site where the developer chose to use 'data' to render the contents of the cell, but I cannot figure out how to add a class to the `<td>` around the data.

I've read the source code and documentation for [Table.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!Element!Table.php/class/Table/8.2.x) and I'm aware of the new `#wrapper_attributes`  but I cannot crack this.

I've tried at least four ways to add the class, and none work.

```
$table['row-' . $row_id] = [

  // Option 1: Class appears on <tr> tag
  '#attributes' => [
    'class' => ['option-1-row-attributes'],
    'id' => 'row-' . $row_id,
    'no_striping' => TRUE,
  ],

  // Option 2: Class appears on <td> tag of first column. 
  'item' => [
    '#markup' => $row['my_item']->label(),
    '#wrapper_attributes' => [   
      'class' => ['option-2-markup-wrapper-attributes'],
    ],
  ],

  // In the following section, the only item that works is
  // the class on the <a> tag.
  'edit_operation' => [
    'data' => [
      '#type' => 'link',
      '#url' => Url::fromRoute('my_module.my_route', ['item' => $row_id]),
      '#title' => $this->t('Edit'),
      '#attributes' => [
        // Option 3: Class appears on the anchor tag
        'class' => ['use-ajax', 'option-3-link-attributes'],
        'data-dialog-type' => 'modal',
        'data-dialog-options' => Json::encode([
          'width' => 700,
        ]),
      ],
      // Option 4: Has no effect.
      '#wrapper_attributes' => [
        'class' => ['option-4-data-wrapper-attributes'],
      ],
    ],
    // Option 5: Update: This appears to be the correct solution! 
    // Class appears on the <td>.
    '#wrapper_attributes' => [
      'class' => ['option-5-wrapper-attributes'],
    ],
    // Option 6: Has no effect.
    '#attributes' => [
      'class' => ['option-6-attributes'],
    ],
    // Option 7: Has no effect.
    'class' => ['option-7-attributes'],
  ],
];
```

Answer (score 14):

After writing out the question in general terms, I've gone back to test again, and have determined that Option 5 in the OP with `'#wrapper_attributes'` at the same level of the `'data'` element does work.  I believe Drupal 8 was aggressively caching the table, because my changes were not showing up even after a `drush cr`.

The rules for adding classes to tables via backend PHP is:

- Table class requires `#attributes`.
- TR row class inside TBODY requires `#attributes`.
- TD cell class inside TBODY requires `#wrapper_attributes`.
- TR row class inside THEAD/TFOOT requires `'class'` and `'data'` containers. 
   Neither `#attributes` nor `#wrapper_attributes` work here.
- TH/TD cell class inside THEAD/TFOOT requires `'class'` and `'data'` containers. 
   Neither `#attributes` nor `#wrapper_attributes` work here.
- *There is no way to add a class directly to a `<thead>` or `<tfoot>` tag without overriding a twig template.*

Here is the most common example for adding classes to the `<tr>` & `<td>` tags inside the main `<tbody>`, as well as to the main `<table>` tag itself:

```
$table = [
  '#type' => 'table',
  '#attributes' => [
    'class' => ['table-class'],
  ],
  'row1' => [
    '#attributes' => [
      'class' => ['tr-class'],
    ],
    // Table data cell using 'data' for renderable elements.
    'column1' => [
      'data' => [
        '#type' => 'link', // Or any other renderable thing.
        '#attributes' => [
          'class' => ['link-class'],
        ],
        // Other elements required to render the link go here...
      ],
      '#wrapper_attributes' => [ // Watch out!
        'class' => ['td-class'],
      ],
    ],
    // Table data cell using '#markup'.
    'column2' => [
      '#markup' => '<span>' . $this->t('text') . '</span>',
      '#wrapper_attributes' => [   
        'class' => ['td-class'],
      ],
    ],
  ],
];
```

Note that the `'class'` container will accept either a string or an array, but I suggest always using an array.

From here, the story gets more complicated.  If you need to add classes to the TR or TD/TH tags inside a THEAD/TFOOT area, the rules change completely.  Neither `#attributes` nor `#wrapper_attributes` work inside `#header` and `#footer` sections and trying to use them produces very strange effects.

The bare minimum structure for tables with header/footer data columns in Drupal 8 is this:

```
$table = [
  '#type' => 'table',
  // Produces <thead> <tr> <th>
  '#header' => [
    'Header 1',
    'Header 2',
    'Header 3',
  ],
  // Produces <tbody> <tr> <td>
  'row1' => [
    'Body 1',
    'Body 2',
    'Body 3',
  ],
  // Produces <tfoot> <tr> <td>
  '#footer' => [
    'Footer 1',
    'Footer 2',
    'Footer 3',
  ],
];
```

You must change the actual structure of the data and introduce two levels of additional multi-dimensional arrays, in order to leverage the `'class'` array index which requires then also introducing the `'data'` array index.  This applies both to the row element and the data cell elements, as seen in the following example:

```
$table = [
  '#type' => 'table',
  // This example works the same way for '#footer'.
  '#header' => [
    // First, introduce an extra level to the array to provide a
    // place to store the class attribute on the <tr> element inside
    // the <thead>.
    [
      'class' => 'thead-tr-class',
      // Next place the columns inside a 'data' container, so that
      // the 'class' can be used.  '#wrapper_attributes' will not
      // work here.
      'data' => [
        // The following line produces data inside a <th>
        // without any class.
        'Header 1',

        // The following lines produce data inside a <th>
        // with a class: th-class.
        [
           'class' => 'th-class',
           'data' => 'Header 2',
           'colspan' => 2
        ],
      ],
    ],
  ],
];
```

The above example `#header` example produces:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr class="thead-tr-class">
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th class="th-class" colspan="2">Header 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm trying to use a colspan in the table header but using your last example I get this errors:

Comment: User error: "0" is an invalid render array key in Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children() (line 97 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Element.php). User error: "class" is an invalid render array key in Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children() (line 97 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Element.php). User error: "data" is an invalid render array key in Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children() (line 97 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Element.php). User error: "colspan" is an invalid render array key in Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children() (line 97 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Element.php).

Comment: I just found another solution for the colspan, take a look here https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/245710/28275