# How to add a colspan in a table header?

Tags: theming, 8, forms

I need to create a table that will have a header with 4 columns and then all the rows will have 5 columns, so I need to add a colspan in the header.

This is an example of what I trying to do:

```
// The table header.
$header = [
  $this->t('Name'),
  $this->t('Description'),
  $this->t('Weight'),
  $this->t('Package'),
];

// The table.
$form['modules'] = [
  '#type' => 'table',
  '#header' => $header,
  '#rows' => [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]],
  '#sticky' => TRUE,
];
```

This code just give something like this:

[image]

But I trying to obtain something like this:

[image]

I tried the last example in [Add a class to a Drupal table cell containing ['data']](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/228988/28275) but just give some errors.

If you go to see the [class Table](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!Element!Table.php/class/Table/8.2.x) you will see an example using the `colspan` in the `'#wrapper_attributes'` but it seems not works for the `'#header'`

I can obtain a similar output just adding an empty header column like this:

```
// The table header.
$header = [
  $this->t('Name'),
  $this->t('Description'),
  $this->t('Weight'),
  '',
  $this->t('Package'),
];
```

This will give something like this:

[image]

But I think that the correct way is adding the colspan property to the header.

Maybe I'm missing something or we just need to wait for [Multi level (multirow) header for table FAPI element](https://www.drupal.org/node/893530) to use the colspan in the table header?

Comment: I found one way to solve this, but I wonder if there is another different way without using the preprocess hooks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just found the solution looking a bit in the [Multi level (multirow) header for table FAPI element](https://www.drupal.org/node/893530) and doing some test.

This is the way that I found:

```
// The table header.
$header = [
  $this->t('Name'),
  $this->t('Description'),
  [
    'data' => $this->t('Weight'),
    'colspan' => 2,
  ],
  $this->t('Package'),
];

// The table.
$form['modules'] = [
  '#type' => 'table',
  '#header' => $header,
  '#rows' => [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]],
  '#sticky' => TRUE,
];
```