# How can I add a CSS class to a #type table render element?

Tags: theming

I was trying to add a custom classname to the table in my custom module. But for some reason it's not working (Drupal 9). I can not get the table class name added into the HTML. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I was following this post below, but no luck.
[Add a class to a Drupal table cell containing ['data']](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/228988/add-a-class-to-a-drupal-table-cell-containing-data)

```
    '#type' => 'table',
    '#attributes' => [
       'class' => ['table-class-name'],
     ],
    '#header' =>  [], /header column goes here/
    '#rows' => [], / data goes here/ 
  ];
```

Comment: That should work - maybe you need to clear your cache.

Comment: Thanks @Jaypan for your time, i have tried to clear cache several times, but i still don't see the table class name in HTML. However, I have added a class to the <th> of the same table that worked okay. So strange...

Comment: Have you tried adding the class to the table template?